# Leer columnas como fecha en múltiples archivos "csv" que están en una lista

Tags: r, date

Tengo 64 archivos `.csv` que he cargado en R a través de una lista:

```
Archivos <- list.files(pattern = "*csv")

Estaciones <- lapply(Archivos, function(x) read.csv(x))
```

Cada archivo (dataframe de la lista) contiene las mismas variables: "Fecha", "Precipitacion", "Temperatura_max", Temperatura_min", "Temperatura_med" y me he percatado que R reconoce la fecha como caracter y no como fecha.

Lo que no quiero es llevar a cabo una función especifica de `lubridate` para cada dataframe como muestro a continuación, sino una única función para todas las tablas:

```
Est_8001$Fecha <- dmy(Est_8001$Fecha)

Est_8004$Fecha <- dmy(Est_8004$Fecha)

Est_8030$Fecha <- dmy(Est_8030$Fecha)
```

Necesito este paso para posteriormente unir todas las variables del mismo tipo con base en la fecha. Espero haber sido claro.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes aprovechar el viaje en el lapply y leer cada archivo uno por uno y al mismo tiempo transformar la variable Fecha a Date

```
Estaciones <- lapply(Archivos, function(x) {
  df = read.csv(x)
  df$Fecha = dmy(df$Fecha)
  return(df)
})
```

Ademas puedes juntar todos los df de la lista con:

```
Estaciones = do.call(rbind,Estaciones)
```

Otra opción usando la librería tidyverse, es usar map_df que cumple el mismo rol que el lapply, pero a diferencia de este, devuelve un df concatenando cada lista que se te genere.

```
Estaciones = Archivos %>% map_df(~ {
  read.csv(.) %>% mutate(Fecha = dmy(Fecha))
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, el cambio de fecha con "lapply" y "dmy" de lubridate me ha servido. Sin embargo tengo problemas con la unión, ya que no todos los dataframes de la lista tienen el mismo número de filas y además deseo integrarlos con base en cada una de las fechas de los registros. Es decir, deseo un dataframe con 65 columnas, una de fechas y 64 columnas correspondientes a la variable temperatura de cada estación. Esto mismo para el resto de variables ( temperatura máx, temperatura min y temperatura med).

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que buscas `read.csv()` tiene el parámetro `colClasses` que permite definir que tipo de dato corresponde a cada columna, cuando no usamos este parámetro, por defecto `read.csv()` solo intenta convertir las columnas a valores numéricos o cadenas. Sin embargo hay otro problema, que es el formato del dato, la forma en que funciona la conversión a `Date` o `Posixct` es esperando el format no ambiguo ISO es decir `%Y/%m/%d`, pero puedes crear una nueva clase que procese otro formato:

```
setAs("character","dmy", function(from) as.Date(from, format="%d/%m/%Y") )

Estaciones <- lapply(Archivos, 
                     function(x) read.csv(x,
                                          colClasses = c('dmy', 'numeric', 'numeric', 
                                                         'numeric', 'numeric'))

)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, lo he intentado pero me aparece error:
> setAs("character","dmy", function(from) as.Date(from, format="%d/%m/%Y") )
in method for ‘coerce’ with signature ‘"character","dmy"’: no definition for class “dmy”
> 
> Estaciones <- lapply(Estaciones, ....
 Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection

Comment: El primero es un warning y puedes ignorarlo, el otro error te esta diciendo que no estás obteniendo el nombre del archivo para procesarlo con read.csv, revisa la variable Estaciones debería contener los nombres de archivos

Comment: Corrijo, el error que sale es:
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  scan() esperaba 'a real', obtuvo 'Nulo'
Y estoy utilizando la lista Archivo como variable

Comment: Se me ocurre que estás tratando alguna columna como numérica y hay algún dato que no puede convertirse a número. Prueba dejar solo solo clases character y Date en colClasses

Comment: Creo que puede ser el hecho de que algunos registros de las variables están como "NA", en todo caso debería indicarle a la función que reconozca los datos ausentes verdad?

Comment: Si es solo ese el problema, a `read.csv()` le puedes indicar cual es el texto para identificar los NA mediante el parámetro `na.strings = '"NA"'`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función [`fread()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/fread) del paquete `data.table`. Generalmente reconoce los formatos de fecha como tal:

```
library(data.table)

> files = list.files(pattern = "df[0-9]")

> dfs = lapply(files, fread)

> lapply(dfs, \(x) head(x, n=2))

#+RESULTS:
[[1]]
  id       date
1  1 1991-01-01
2  2 1991-01-02

[[2]]
  id       date
1  1 1911-01-01
2  2 1911-01-02

[[3]]
  id       date
1  1 1891-01-01
2  2 1891-01-02
```

```
> dfs = data.frame(dfs[1])
> class(dfs2$date)
#+RESULTS:
: [1] "IDate" "Date"
```

Si los datos están en formato dia-mes-año el código sería:

```
dfs = lapply(fcsv, \(x) fread(x, colClasses = c("date" = "Date")))
```

```
> dput(dfs)
#+RESULTS:
list(structure(list(id = 1:5, date = c("1991-01-01", "1991-01-02", 
"1991-01-03", "1991-01-04", "1991-01-05")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), structure(list(id = 1:5, date = c("1911-01-01", "1911-01-02", 
"1911-01-03", "1911-01-04", "1911-01-05")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), structure(list(id = 1:5, date = c("1891-01-01", "1891-01-02", 
"1891-01-03", "1891-01-04", "1891-01-05")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)))
```

Comment: ¿Esto funciona con formato dia - mes -año?

Comment: Gracias por mencionar este punto: efectivamente, ese abordaje no funciona con el formato dia - mes - año.